# selectedIndex is undefined in dropdownlist mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

i am binding dropdown list but zero index showing undefined, below is my code.

```
  <select ng-model="CategoryID" id="CategoryID" name="CategoryID" class="form-control margin-bottom-15" required>          
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
        {
            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
        }
    </select>
```

after rendering its showing like...

```
<select ng-model="CategoryID" id="CategoryID" name="CategoryID" class="form-control margin-bottom-15 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" required="">
   <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>                          
   <option value="1">Category1</option>
   <option value="2">Category2</option>
</select>
```

in controller..

```
 private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategories()
    {

        var catg = database.Categories
                    .Select(x =>
                            new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.CategoryID.ToString(),
                                Text = x.CategoryName
                            });

        return new SelectList(catg, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

Comment: Possibly, the problem might be in the data that is binded. Can you post that as well ?

Comment: i have added my controller code

Comment: The code seems fine. What results are you receiving under `catg` ?

Comment: i am receiving 2 list like Category 1 and Category 2

Comment: <select ng-model="CategoryID" id="CategoryID" name="CategoryID" class="form-control margin-bottom-15" required>   <option value="0">Select</option>        
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
        {
            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
        }
    </select>

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the values that your binding to because they probably look like this:

```
[
    { Text: "" },
    { Text: "Category1", Value: 1 }
    { Text: "Category2", Value: 2 }
]
```

Or you really have this value `? undefined:undefined ?` as the `Value` property of your first item.

Comment: i have only Category1 and Category2, but i don't know how its showing ? undefined:undefined ?

Comment: @Ethan Please inspect the model and see what members the categories have.